Is it possible to save a notepad text (.txt) file to a Latex (.tex) file?
I am trying to compile and test a file in Latex/Domino using a text file in Notepad that has a script/code in it. Is it possible to convert the notepad txt file to tex somehow? Could a txt file be used in Latex instead? The ultimate goal is to eventually upload a word doc into Latex format.
When I save the notepad file to my computer the only option it allows me to save is as a txt file. Through additional researching, it looks like Notepad only allows txt files. I do not want to use one of those online conversion websites either.
Thanks!

If you want to convert a .doc file to latex, have a look at pandoc.

Welcome. // In hindsight your question contains more than one. In future it will be better to prepare one question at a time (this is due to the concept 1 question == 1 problem, each answer == 1 solution).

Probably a XY question. With pandoc you can convert directly from .docx to  .tex (well, really it is not  direct, but  who cares). Convert first to .txt   have sense only if you find munch easier lost all the word format (bold fonts, sections, italics, links, etc.)  and start from raw text,  than fix the possible issues of the direct conversion of a  devilishly complex format in Word that cannot be well exported.

Notepad related
It's the content that matters, not the extension, see below. E.g. save this as test.txt:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}

On your command line (terminal), set to that directory,  run, where > denotes the prompt:
>pdflatex test.txt

Which creates as test.pdf, here in a browser:

You can use notepad AND save it as test.tex: just overwrite it.

However, if you run a framework, it may expect .tex files, unless you otherwise specify in its preferences. But frameworks often come with an appropriate editor, i.e. which takes care of file extensions.
Reworking your file
It has to contain Latex statements, of course. So if they are missing, you'll need to add them. Or follow the route via pandoc, as samcarter proposed.
To markup code listings, use e.g. package listings.
